# SQL - Get Top 1 for each item in a list with many records

Tags: sql, database

I have the following table:

```
ID | Plate | RecordedAt
   |       |
   |       |
```

For each plate I can have N records.

I'm working with the following query:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * 
 FROM table
 WHERE table.Plate IN ('plate1', 'plate2', 'plate3') 
 ORDER BY c.Recordedat DESC
```

The problem is that this query returns only one record for all the list.

I need the top 1 of each item in the list.

Is there any way to achieve this with only one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by plate order by recordedat desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where table.Plate in ('plate1', 'plate2', 'plate3')
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: but here it does for all the records in the table, not the ones in my list, the plate list is sent by parameter, It's not all the plates in the table

Comment: @pedrodotnet . . .  You can add a `where` clause, as I just did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cte in sql for this situation like following:

```
with TopOneOfTables
as
{
    select  yt.*,
            row_number() over (partition by Plate order by RecordedAt desc) as RowNo
            from yourTable yt
      Where yt.Plate in ('plate1', 'plate2', 'plate3') 
}

select *
from TopOneOfTables
where RowNo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Basically you need to partition the data set by one column, but you also want to order each partition. Thats where keep dense_rank comes in.

```
select distinct plate, 
max(ID) keep(dense_rank FIRST order by RecordedAt 
desc nulls last ) over ( partition by plate ) as required_field 
from table 
where table.Plate in ('plate1', 'plate2', 'plate3') ;
```